# Can Android package names contain only letters and periods?

Tags: android

I'm trying to scrape data from [www.apkmirror.com](http://www.apkmirror.com/) which includes the package name of apps. For example, below

[image]

the package name is "`com.lenovo.anyshare.gps`". I'm considering whether to use the [pyparsing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/2.2.0) expression

```
Word(alphas + ".")
```

for the package name, meaning `[a-zA-z.]` as a regular expression. Is this OK, or would it be too restrictive in some cases? (I wasn't able to find much about restrictions on the package name on https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).

Comment: Any valid Java package name works. Underscores are allowed. Digits are allowed AFAIK, though not as the leading character of a segment. Java reserved words (e.g., `int`) are not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)'s comment, I'm assuming for the moment that any character is allowed except a whitespace. (I've updated the regular expression to `\S+`, since there should be at least one character).